# Prove that the sequence $X_n = Z_n/ \sqrt{1+\log{n}}, ~ n\geq 1$ is almost surely bounded for $Z_n ~ i.i.d. ~ N(0,1)$.

Tags: probability

Let $Z_1,Z_2,\ldots$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ random variables. Let $X_n = Z_n/ \sqrt{1+\log{n}}, ~ n\geq 1$. Question is to show that $X_n$ is almost surely bounded.

Proceeding as following :

Step 1. I have a proof that $P(|X_n|\geq \lambda)\leq n^{-\lambda^2/2} \exp(-\lambda^2/2)$.

Step 2. Then how do I bound $P(sup_{n\geq 1} |X_n| > \lambda)$ for $\lambda \geq 2$, so that I can show that $X_n$ is almost surely bounded?

Comment: I should point out, in Step 2 you ask to bound this tail for $\lambda \ge 2$. Since you're taking $\sup_n$ not $\limsup_n$, you won't get an interesting bound for some 'small' number like $2$. Indeed, in your comment to my answer, you find 'some $M$' such that this holds. This isn't an issue, as you only want to show boundedness, but I thought I should point it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to how Mike Earnest has suggested (although I'm sure his suggestion will work!), you can use a Borel-Cantelli argument. You say you have the bound
$$ P(|X_n| \ge \lambda) \le n^{-\lambda^2/2} \exp(-\lambda^2/2). \tag{1} $$
Now let us define events
$$ A_n = \{ |X_n| \ge \alpha \}. $$
By $(1)$, we have that
$$ P(A_n) \le n^{-\alpha^2/2}. $$
For Borel-Cantelli, we want $\sum_n P(A_n)$ to converge, ie for the infinite sum to exist (and be finite). This says that we may take, for example, $\alpha = 2$, as then $P(A_n) \le n^{-2}$ and so $\sum_n P(A_n) < \infty$ (the exact value is irrelevant; it just matters that it's finite). Hence Borel-Cantelli then says that
$$ P(|X_n| \ge 2 \text{ i.o.} ) = 0, 
\quad \text{so} \quad
P({\limsup}_n |X_n| \le 2) = 1.$$
Once you have that the $\limsup$ is bounded, you can transfer this over to the whole process; I leave this as an exercise -- which you have completed correctly in the comment below.

Solution by the OP to the exercise (included a suggestion from Sam) :

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. $P(\lim \sup_n |X_n| \leq 2) = 1 \implies \lim_m P(\cap_{n \geq m} \{X_n \leq 2\}) =1 \implies$ $$\exists N\in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } P(\cap_{n \geq N} \{X_n \leq 2\}) \geq 1-\epsilon /2$$

Noting $X_i$ i.i.d. $N(0,1)$, $\exists M>2$ s.t. $P(|X_n| > M) < \epsilon/(2M)$. So, $$P(\cup_{n<N} |X_n| > M) \leq \sum_{n<N} P(|X_n|>M) < \epsilon/2$$

Now, $$P(\cap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{X_n \leq M\}) \geq P(\cap_{n\geq N} \{X_n \leq M\}) - P(\cup_{n<N} |X_n| > M) > 1-\epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon >0$ arbitrary we have that $P(\cap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\{X_n \leq M\}) = 1 \implies P(\sup |X_n| \leq M) = 1$.

---

Comment: Thanks it helped. If interested, this can fill the last part:


Fix $\epsilon > 0$. $P(\lim \sup_n |X_n| \leq 2) = 1 \implies \lim_m P(\cap_{n\geq m}\{X_n \leq 2\})=1\implies\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.  $P(\cap_{n \geq N} \{X_n \leq 2\})\geq 1-\epsilon /2$.


Noting $X_i$ iid $N(0,1)$, $\exists M>0$ s.t.$P(|X_n| > M)< \epsilon /(2M)$. So, $P(\cup_{n<N}|X_n|>M)\leq \sum_{n<N}P(|X_n|>M)< \epsilon/2$.

Now,$P(\cap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\{X_n \leq \max{2,M}\})\geq P(\cap_{n\geq N} \{X_n \leq \max{2,M}\}) - P(\cup_{n<N} |X_n| > \max{2,M}) > 1-\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon >0$ the result follows.

Comment: Perfect: that is the exact method that I was going to do! If you like, you can edit my answer and put "exercise done by OP..." and then put in your details; might be easier to read than in a comment. Note that you can also get rid of the rather ugly $\max\{2,M\}$ by saying $\exists M > 2$ such that... (this is clearly true since $|X_n|$ has an exponentially decaying tail, and you're only asking for inverse-linear decay)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sup |X_n|$ is greater than $\lambda$ if and only if at least one of the $|X_n|>\lambda$. So you need a bound for the probability of the union:
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{n\ge0} |X_n|>\lambda\right)\le \dots
$$
What ways do you know to bound the probability of the union of events?

Comment: Once this is done, there is still work to do before one can conclude. Hence, this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Did It seemed to me the only part they were asking about was bounding $P(\sup_n |X_n|>\lambda)$, and they wanted to to the rest of the conclusion by themselves. But perhaps I misinterpreted.